# How to make Software Updater show up less often?

Tags: updates, software-center

Currently I have the settings for "Software Updater" set as follows:
[image: Software updater settings]

However, I get prompts for software updates such as the following every day:

[image: Software update]

This is very annoying.  How can I make notifications show up less often?

Comment: may i know in the 1st pic what is your chosen option for "when there are security updates"

Comment: @PRATAP it is grayed out and I can pick anything for it so I guess my choice is None?

Comment: Have you ever changed any settings related to that particular thing? By default it can't be none. Any how I have done some search on it. Security updates are tend to pop up immediately when they are available..there is no setting to hide this pop-up. To test it I have unticked "important security updates" .

Comment: @PRATAP You must be onto something.  I am confused as to why I can't toggle that option (I guess another question for SO) and that must be the cause.  Thanks for your idea here.